# How to find point or interval of intersection in nested interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

so I am give a problem which sets sequences $a_n$=1-1/n and $b_n$= 1+1/n and the interval $I_n$ As [$a_n$,$b_n$]. How would you find the intersection of these two sequences by nested interval theorem or otherwise?  I know when you draw it it's clear that it is 1 but how might one do it rigorously?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a_n < 1 < b_n$ for all positive integers $n$, so $1$ is in the intersection.
Any other real number $y$ is either greater than $1$ or less than $1$.
In each case, show that $y$ is outside the interval if $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a problem like this, where the correct solution is very easy to see, the best method is to first claim what the solution is and then rigorously show the claimed solution indeed satisfies the problem's condition.

**Claim:** $\cap_n [a_n,b_n] = \{1\}$

For one direction "$\supset$", by construction, $1\in \cap_n [a_n,b_n]$.

For the other direction "$\subset$", use Robert Israel's hint, argue by contraposition